# Why is the size of a folder different when copied to a different location on the same disk?

Tags: windows-10, windows-explorer, ntfs, teracopy

I copied a folder to a different location on the same disk, and I noticed that both its size as well as the size on the disk is different in the new location.

So, I tried using [TeraCopy](https://www.codesector.com/teracopy) to copy the folder with the "Verify files after copy" option checked. However, the sizes are still different!

[image]

**As can be seen in the screenshot above**, both the size and the size on disk are different in different locations!!

Comment: run defrag on the drive, see if it changes the sizes. Windows frags files when copied, defrag may solve the size differences.

Comment: Thanks. I just did so. There is still the same difference in the actual folder size (828 Bytes)! I do not know if I should worry about this small difference.

Comment: It might be a bit of a pain with an 8GB folder, but there are plenty of utilities to create checksum files in bulk. I might suggest creating checksums for the items in the entire orginal folder and then run those checksums against the items in your copied folder. It's only a possibility but some of the files may have had issues during copying and lost a few bytes.

Comment: Thanks. The tool I used to copy (TeraCopy) already does checksum for every single file it copies. No issues was reported.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to investigate the difference, I wrote a small Java program that compares all the files in all folders and sub-folders, recursively. It turned out that the difference is only in `desktop.ini` files.